# How can I modify bootstrap text input fields to have text cut off the top on focus?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I imagine this is going to be a bit of a difficult problem, but I'm curious how I can use `CSS` **(potentially animations)** to modify `bootstrap` to have functionality similar to this:

[image]

I've found a few different examples, but they only really help with getting a `material design-esque` look, like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to implement this? I'm stuck

Comment: What did you do to solve the problem? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also say something similar 
your HTML should look

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="error-message">is required field.</div>
    <input class="form-control" required placeholder="Input field" /> 
 </div>
```

CSS should be :

```
.form-group .error-message{
  display:none;
}
.form-group.required .form-control{
   border-color:red;
}
.form-group.required .error-message{
   display:inline-block;
   color:red;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:#fff;
   margin-top: -10px;
   margin-left: 20px; 
}
```

and JS can be :

```
(function(){
  $('.form-control[required]').on('blur',function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
      $(this).parent().addClass('required');
    }
  });
})();
```

You can see it in action : https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/EXQzJK

Comment: Woah this is awesome -- let me grab some time to look into it and report back!

Comment: Glad to hear that, btw If you want to be able to control what message you want to show the user, you can add a data attribute to form-control element and then in the JS method based on that attribute you can show different messages for different inputs.

Comment: I'm using Typescript and Angular 2 so the behavior code itself will look a bit different, but much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

This might help you. Check the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xo5gdp8r/

```
span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 5px;
    color: red;
    background: #fff;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

input {
   margin: 15px 10px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

You need to wrap it inside a div and provide position as relative to the div.

Comment: This is awesome as well -- you guys are wizards